# Cohomology of sheaves for sites and Galois cohomology

Tags: reference-request, cohomology

Hello,

I am looking for a reference (if it exists) that makes the link between cohomology of sheaves for sites and Galois cohomology :

quickly said, I would like to see Galois cohomology (at least in the commutative case) as the cohomology of a sheaf over the étale site of extensions of k.

By the way, what is a reference for cohomology of sites ?

Thanks

Comment: Milne's notes on étale cohomology. Tamme's book on étale cohomology.

Comment: Both of Mariano's references are good.  Also, there's plenty of lectures notes and unofficial write-ups of this material all over the web.  For example, try googling "mcgill seminar on cohomology" (no quotes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two references from my comment above, now with links!

- Milne, James S. Étale cohomology. Princeton Mathematical Series, 33. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J., 1980. xiii+323 pp. [MR0559531](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0559531) You can get another set of notes on étale cohomology from his [web page](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/lec.html): «in comparison with my book, the emphasis is on heuristic arguments rather than formal proofs and on varieties rather than schemes».
- Tamme, Günter. Introduction to étale cohomology. Translated from the German by Manfred Kolster. Universitext. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1994. x+186 pp. [MR1317816](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1317816)

Answer (score 7):

I will also add:

E. Freitag, R. Kiehl: "Etale cohomology and the Weil conjectures"

There are also some notes for a course by de Jong given at Columbia University which can be found here:

http://math.columbia.edu/~pugin/Teaching/Etale.html

Comment: The notes aren't there, but I love the picture.

Comment: The notes *are* there, actually.


Comment: You are correct.  I am getting too old to notice links on a webpage.

Comment: I didn't add a direct link to the notes so as a) people could see the photo b) I could also add SGA4 1/2 to the references :) 

Answer (score 4):

Barry Mazur has also written an article about this: [Notes on étale cohomology of number fields](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/2010/582e/refs/mazur-notes_on_etale_cohomology_of_number_fields_original.pdf).
I hope this helps.

Comment: A more permanent copy at numdam: http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1973_4_6_4_521_0